# determine if a number is within a certain percentage of another number

Tags: math

How do i determine if a number falls within a certain percentage of another number?

E.g. the starting number is 17%. And i want to check if X% is within 5% of the starting number (17%). Any tips please as my attempt 17 - 5 <= X don't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about arithmetic, not about computer programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic algorithm to calculate if a number falls in a percentage range of another number :

```
bool isWithinPercentage(int numberA, int numberB, int range)
{
    float percentage = 0
    percentage = ((numberB - numberA) * 100) / numberA

    return percentage <= range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The edit queue of Rushguy23's answer is full, so here's a suggested corrected version, using abs(percentage) to check the absolute value of percentage in case numberA>numberB:

```
bool isWithinPercentage(int numberA, int numberB, int range)
{
    float percentage = 0
    percentage = (numberB - numberA) * 100 / numberA

    return abs(percentage) <= range
}
```